# Cannot reseed the Table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, dml

I have below tables that I am trying to delete its record and reseeding it after deleting it and it is throwing an error that I cannot reseed the table, saying that the parameter 3 is incorrect. as can be seen the parameter 3 is going correct as it is a variable

```
Delete Table1
where Category = 'category'

Declare @NEXTIdentity int = 0
SELECT @NEXTIdentity = MAX(ID) + 1
FROM Table1

    
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Table1, Reseed, @NEXTIdentity)
```

Error message

> Msg 2560, Level 16, State 9, Line 24
> Parameter 3 is incorrect for this DBCC statement.

I Tried explicitly setting the variable which works

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Table1, Reseed, 1)
```

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table1` after the delete ?

Comment: You use an IDENTITY column because you want a unique number but don't care what it is. Stop worrying about making it "pretty" - no need for reseeding.

Comment: @Delta32000 the table is empty almost 5 to 6 rows deleted, gives me nothing as the table is empty but the variable NEXTIdentity is set to 1 after above statement execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup you can pass variables to DBCC (at least with my conf : mssql 16)

try :

```
Delete Table1
where Category = 'category'

Declare @NEXTIdentity int = 0
SELECT @NEXTIdentity = ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) + 1
FROM Table1

    
DBCC CHECKIDENT(Table1, Reseed, @NEXTIdentity)
```

Note that `NULL + 1 = NULL`

Comment: Yes you are correct why do the DBCC CHECKIDENT (Table1, Reseed, @NEXTIdentity) , requires the variable @NEXTIdentity to be not null how come, as the sql does not compile it seems that it is compiling the function DBCC CHECKIDENT (Table1, Reseed, @NEXTIdentity) and alerting it to be not null ahead of time

Comment: What is your config ? version ? ...

Comment: My sql server version is 13.0.6419.1, if that is what you are asking, what is config?

Comment: If you're deleting everything from the table, which is implied you aren't, then why not just `TRUNCATE` the table, which also reseeds the `IDENTITY`, @kinnangiant ?

Comment: Not deleting everything, it happens to delete everything due to very small dataset

"Delete Table1
where Category = 'category'"